# Show that $\xi (\lambda) \equiv \left | A - \lambda I \right | $, and find the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratics

Let a $2 \times 2$ matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & \beta \\ 
\gamma & \delta
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Show that then $\xi (\lambda) \equiv \left | A - \lambda I \right | = \lambda^{2} - (\alpha  + \delta) \lambda + (\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma)$, and find the eigenvalues.

**My attempt:** I have found that $$ A - \lambda I = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha - \lambda &\beta \\ 
\gamma & \delta - \lambda
\end{bmatrix},$$

and then solved for its determinant to obtain 
$$\left | A - \lambda I \right | = (\alpha - \lambda)(\delta - \lambda) - \beta \lambda $$
$$= \lambda^{2} - (\alpha  + \delta) \lambda + (\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma).$$

Then I have set the determinant to zero and need to solve the following equation: 
$$ \lambda^{2} - (\alpha  + \delta) \lambda + (\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma) = 0.$$

**EDIT:** Typo fixed

I have tried the quadratic formula and have been getting something quite messy
$$ \lambda = \frac{\alpha + \delta \pm \sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\delta^{2}-2\alpha \delta + 4 \beta \gamma} }{2}.$$

Comment: You just did (though I'm not confident that you didn't make an error). It doesn't simplify nicely unless the numbers are nice. By the way, using "det" instead of absolute value bars is not much longer and is much clearer. Also, you can present it in a somewhat cleaner manner by introducing $T=\alpha+\delta$ and $\Delta = \alpha \delta - \beta \gamma$. Then $\xi(\lambda)=\lambda^2-T\lambda+\Delta$ and the quadratic formula looks simpler.

Comment: Everyting you did is correct. You did find the eigenvalues. What else do you want?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: "Everyting you did is correct". Mh, except maybe for the typo in the final answer...

Comment: @Yves Daoust Which typo? I did not see it.

Comment: Do you plan to leave the last sentence "Any thoughts on how I can find the eigenvalues" ?

Comment: @Yves Ah good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is

$$\lambda=\frac{\alpha+\delta\pm\sqrt{(\alpha-\delta)^2+4\beta\gamma}}2.$$

Comment: Could you please show some previous steps? I don't quite see how you obtained the second term.

Comment: @OGC: you have them but you made a calculation error.

Comment: How did you get the second term?

Comment: @OGC: redo your calculation.

Comment: I did and still not seeing it. What are your coefficients in the quadratic formula? I have $a=1$, $b = -(\alpha + \beta)$, and $c = \alpha \delta - \beta \gamma$.

Comment: @OGC: mh, this is wrong, and in addition does not lead to the final formula you wrote. Two typos now. Don't rush.

Comment: @OGC: as a check, try your formulas with a unit matrix.

Comment: Ah now I see how you got the answer. I've fixed my typo.

Comment: @OGC: typos are smarter than us ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The zeros of the quadratic you obtained are the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you apply the quadratic formula, you should find that
$$
b^2 - 4ac = \\
[-(\alpha + \delta)]^2 - 4(\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma) = \\
\alpha^2 + 2 \alpha \delta + \delta^2 - 4 \alpha \delta + 4 \beta \gamma =\\
\alpha^2 - 2 \alpha \delta + \delta^2 + 4 \beta \gamma =\\
(\alpha - \delta)^2 + 4 \beta \gamma
$$

Comment: It seem to be me that you have a typo on the third line. Should it be $\alpha^{2} + 2 \alpha \delta + \delta^{2} - 4 \alpha \delta + 4 \beta \gamma$?

Comment: @OGC yes, fixed.